# Positioning Views in ForEach SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I would like to add animating views to a parent view. I know that the parent view needs to position the children but I'm having trouble coming up with the formula to implement. I have the first couple of views right but once I get to 4 and up its a problem! I would like the views to appear in a grid with 3 columns.

[image: Animated View of circles appearing and moving]

Here is some reproducible code ready to be copy and pasted.

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomView: View, Identifiable {

  @State private var startAnimation = false
  let id = UUID()

  var body: some View {
    Circle()
      .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
      .scaleEffect(x: startAnimation ? 2 : 1,
                   y: startAnimation ? 2 : 1)
      .animation(Animation.interpolatingSpring(mass: 2, stiffness: 20, damping: 1, initialVelocity: 1))
      .onAppear {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
          self.startAnimation = true
        }
      }
  }
}

struct StartView: View {

  @State private var userSelection: [CustomView] = []

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: -20) {
      Button("Add View") {
        self.userSelection.append(CustomView())
      }
      LazyVGrid(columns: gridStyle) {
        ForEach(Array(userSelection.enumerated()), id: \.0 ){ index, equip in
          CustomView()
            .position(x: widthBasedOn(index: index), y: heightBasedOn(index: index))

        }
        .padding([])
      }
      .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.5,
             height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.8)
    }
  }
  let gridStyle = [
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 0, maximum: 100), spacing: -50),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 0, maximum: 100), spacing: -50),
    GridItem(.flexible(minimum: 0, maximum: 100), spacing: -50)
  ]

  private func widthBasedOn(index: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if index % 3 != 0 {
      if index > 3 {
        let difference = index - 4
        return CGFloat(index * difference * 100)
      }
      let answer = CGFloat(index * 100)
      print("\(index) width should be: \(answer)")
      return answer
    }
    return 0
  }

  private func heightBasedOn(index: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if index > 3 && index < 6 {
      return 100
    }
    return 200
  }
}

struct EquipmentSelectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    StartView()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since most of your question is somewhat vague, and I am not sure about the specifics, this is my solution. Feel free to respond, and I will be glad to answer your question further with more tailored solution.

I removed many of your code that was unnecessary or overly-complicated. For example, I removed the `widthBasedOn` and `heightBasedOn` methods. I also changed the array property `var userSelection: [CustomView]` to `var numberOfViews = 0`.

**Note:** Both your original code and my solution cause all the circles to wiggle up and down, whenever a new circle is added.

I suggest that you copy paste this code snippet, run it in Xcode, and see if this is what you want.

```
struct CustomView: View, Identifiable {
  @State private var startAnimation = false
  let id = UUID()
  
  var body: some View {
      Circle()
        //Changing the frame size of the circle, making it bigger or smaller
        .frame(width: startAnimation ? 100 : 50, height: startAnimation ? 100 : 50)
          .animation(Animation.interpolatingSpring(mass: 2, stiffness: 20, damping: 1, initialVelocity: 1))
          .onAppear {
              DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
              self.startAnimation = true
              }
          }
  }
}

struct StartView: View {
    //View will display this number of circles
    @State private var numberOfViews = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack() {
            Button("Add View") {
                self.numberOfViews += 1
            }
            .padding(.top, 100)
            Spacer()
            LazyVGrid(columns: gridStyle) {
                //Add a new circle CustomView() to the LazyVGrid for each number of views
                ForEach(0..<numberOfViews, id: \.self ){view in
                    CustomView()
                }
            }
            
            
        }
    }
    //3 columns, flexible spacing for elments. In this case, equal amount of spacing.
    let gridStyle = [
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        GridItem(.flexible()),
        
    ]
}
  
  struct EquipmentSelectionView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
      static var previews: some View {
          StartView()
      }
  }
```

#### Limiting number of circles

To limit the number of circles:

```
if numberOfViews < 9 {
    self.numberOfViews += 1
}
```

#### Positioning the button

To position the button, you can add padding:

```
Button("Add View") {
  if numberOfViews < 9 {
      self.numberOfViews += 1
  }
}
.padding(.top, 100)
```

#### Overlap vs. No Overlap

Using there `.frame` modifier will not have any overlap:

```
.frame(width: startAnimation ? 100 : 50, height: startAnimation ? 100 : 50)
```

But if you do want overlap, use `.scaleEffect`:

```
.scaleEffect(x: startAnimation ? 2 : 1,
             y: startAnimation ? 2 : 1)
```

P.S. Unfortunately, I can't show you the results with GIF images because Stackoverflow keep giving me upload errors.

Comment: Very helpful, that's exactly what I was looking for. I think a key point was animating the frame instead of the scaleEffect was helpful? I'm going to review that in Xcode